# How to set my own message in my custom exception in Java that can be retrieved my getMessage() BUT WITHOUT using the constructor, is there any way?

Tags: java, exception, constructor, throwable

I'm just learning about exception handling in Java. What I would like to know is rather than trying something like say:

```
throw new Exception("My Message");
```

and

```
String message=ex.getMessage();

System.out.println(message);
```

Take a look at the code below ,

```
class ExceptionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExceptionTest t1=new ExceptionTest();

        try {
            t1.riskyMethod();//call the risky or exception throwing method
        } catch(MyException myex) {
            System.out.println("Exception has been thrown");

            String message=myex.getMessage();//get the String passed during exception call
            System.out.println("The message retrieved is "+message);
            myex.printStackTrace();//prints name of exception and traces the function call stack
        }

    }//main ends

    void riskyMethod() throws MyException {//a method that can throw an excpetion
        int rand=(int)(Math.random()*10);///Math.rand return 0 to .9 range value

        if(rand>5) {
            //throw new MyException();  or try this
            //      MyException myexception=new MyException();
            //      myexception.setMessage("HI THIS IS A SAMPLE MESSAGE");
            String mymessage="Sample Exception Message...";
            throw new MyException(mymessage);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("No exception");
    }
}//Exception class ends
```

While this works fine I want to know if I can avoid calling super(message) etc 
and just set some variable 'message' in my subclass MyException that changes the message retrieved on a call to exception.getMessage()

In other words what is the name of the string variable that store the message string passed to the constructor and can I set it manually, is it final or private, if so is there any setter method for it. Sorry I tried but am just a beginner and have trouble navigating the API

Comment: I'm just Curious,i Would like to look into the Exception Class Instance variables etc , is it available?

Comment: The variable you're interested in isn't in `Exception` - it's in `Throwable`. It's `private` but not `final`, however `Throwable` doesn't provide a setter (or mutator if you prefer) for it, so the only way to change its value would be through reflection. However, don't. That way madness lies. If all you want to do is look at the source code, then you'll really want to be using an IDE. In Eclipse, you can CTRL-click on a class name to be taken to its source code. If you're using NetBeans, then I believe it's CTRL-Shift-B with the cursor inside the class name.

Comment: I haven't really used IDE's as yet , will try , in the meantime can you please link link or provide Throwable's source code

Comment: I was unable to find the source code, but here is the JavDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html

Comment: This is [OpenJDK's Throwable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Throwable.java#Throwable.0detailMessage) class on grepcode. If you want to see the one specific to your JDK installation, then you should be able to find it on your computer. Traditionally you'd have installed the JDK to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.<version>`. Inside that directory should be a `src.zip` file, which contains all of the .java files for the JRE. You'll want Throwable.java inside java/lang.

Comment: Thanks found it ,                                                                       'private String detailMessage;'
                                                                    'public Throwable(String message) {'
        'fillInStackTrace();'
        'detailMessage = message;'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there is no way of setting the message manually, you could however just use your own variable instead and override the **getMessage()** method

Example:

```
public class MyException extends Exception{

    public String message;

    public MyException(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    // Overrides Exception's getMessage()
    @Override
    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }

    // Testing
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyException e = new MyException("some message");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks that Worked,and btw do the API docs not provide information about a class's instance fields ,why?

Comment: SamTebbs33: Didn't you want to override also setMessage and define the MyException() constructor?  @Droidics: There is no doc on private fields.

Comment: There is no **setMessage** method, have I not defined the constructor? @FlorianF

Comment: Done overriding , works now , is the variable I was looking for 'detailedMessage'?

Comment: @SamTebbs33.  (sorry, I meant _define_ a setMessage).  I understand Droid didn't want to provide the message in the constructor.  He wanted to provide it in a setMessage or hard-code it.

Comment: Ah, well I made the **message** variable public so that it could be set!

Comment: I just tried e.getMessage() without overriding and passing the message in the constructor and I did not get any problem atleast in java 8

Answer (score 0):

> String Variable that store the message string passed to the constructor and can i set it manually

There is no such field in Java.

But to help you, i suggest using `ArrayList`to store Exceptions Strings. You can easily manipulate data with this by using `add()`,`remove()`, `indexOf()` methods . All additional information about class you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Keep in mind that this is not only way to store sets of data, so i suggest to read documentation.

Comment: getting excepiton in main method as follows:"non-static variable message cannot be referenced from a context"